# Hide or show inputs according to a pickerinput choice in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a shiny application where I create a certain number of inputs based on a numeric input.
These inputs are :

- Some text to display which input number you are at
- A pickerinput with the selected choice "" and the possible choice c("", "-", some agricultural fodder)
- A numericInput to be the yield of the agricultural fodder
- These inputs (apart from the first one giving the input number) are repeated three times on the same horizontal line (column(3, ...), column(3, ...), column(3, ...), column(3, ...)).

The user won't necessarily use all 3 inputs horizontally, and I want to display only the pickerinputs as long as it hasn't taken a value other than "" or "-" in the pickerinput.

I've also added a div to add space between my elements in case the output's numericInput is hidden.

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuKy9.jpg)

So I use the map function, looping over the number of inputs I have, and use the hide/show function.

below is a reproductible example of a shiny app with this problem

```r
# Libraries
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(purrr)

# Function :
inputsPrairie <- function(nbInputs, idPickerInput, choices, idEspace, idNumericInput, tagList){
  base::lapply(1 : nbInputs, function(i){
    
    picker_i <- pickerInput(inputId = paste0(idPickerInput, i), label = "", choices = choices,
                            multiple = FALSE, options = pickerOptions(title = "Choix du devenir"))
    
    espace <- div(HTML(""), id = paste0(idEspace, i))
    
    rendement_i <- numericInput(inputId = paste0(idNumericInput, i),
                                label = "Rendement", value = NULL, min = 0, step = 0.1)
    
    res <- tagAppendChild(tagList, picker_i)
    res <- tagAppendChild(res, espace)
    res <- tagAppendChild(res, rendement_i)
    return(res)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
  ),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        mainPanel(
          column(12, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_titre_prairie")),
          column(12, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_nb_prairies")),
          column(12, class = 'espace3'),
          column(3, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_numero_prairie")),
          column(3, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir1")),
          column(3, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir2")),
          column(3, uiOutput("MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir3")),
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$MOD2_UI_titre_prairie <- renderUI({
    div(HTML("Production de l'herbe :"), class = 'sous_titre_parametrage3')
  })
  
  output$MOD2_UI_nb_prairies <- renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId = "MOD2_nb_prairies",
                 label = "Nombre d'itinéraires culturaux différents",
                 value = NULL,
                 max = 100,
                 min = 0)
  })
  
  output$MOD2_UI_numero_prairie <- renderUI({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    res <- tagList()
    
    base::lapply(1 : input$MOD2_nb_prairies, function(i){
      
      numero_i <- div(HTML("Itinéraire herbe ", i), class = 'numero_prairie')
      
      res <- tagAppendChild(res, numero_i)
      
      res
    })
  })
  
  output$MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    res <- tagList()
    
    choices_D <- c("-", "Foin", "Regain", "Pâturage")
    
    res <- inputsPrairie(nbInputs = input$MOD2_nb_prairies,
                         idPickerInput = "MOD2_type_devenir_prairie1_",
                         choices = choices_D, idEspace = "espace_prairie1_",
                         idNumericInput = "MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie1_", tagList = res)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    1 : input$MOD2_nb_prairies %>%
      map(function(i){
        req(!is.null(input[[paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie1_", i)]]))
        req(!is.null(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie1_", i)]]))
        if(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie1_", i)]] == "" |
           input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie1_", i)]] == "-"){
          shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie1_", i))
          shinyjs::addCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie1_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
        }else{
          shinyjs::show(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie1_", i))
          shinyjs::removeCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie1_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
        }
      })
  })
  
  output$MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    res <- tagList()
    
    choices_D <- c("-", "Foin", "Regain", "Pâturage")
    
    res <- inputsPrairie(nbInputs = input$MOD2_nb_prairies,
                         idPickerInput = "MOD2_type_devenir_prairie2_",
                         choices = choices_D, idEspace = "espace_prairie2_",
                         idNumericInput = "MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie2_", tagList = res)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    base::lapply(1 : input$MOD2_nb_prairies, function(i){
      req(!is.null(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie2_", i)]]))
      if(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie2_", i)]] == "" |
         input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie2_", i)]] == "-"){
        shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie2_", i))
        shinyjs::addCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie2_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
      }else{
        shinyjs::show(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie2_", i))
        shinyjs::removeCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie2_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
      }
    })
  })
  
  output$MOD2_UI_prairie_devenir3 <- renderUI({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    res <- tagList()
    
    choices_D <- c("-", "Foin", "Regain", "Pâturage")
    
    res <- inputsPrairie(nbInputs = input$MOD2_nb_prairies,
                         idPickerInput = "MOD2_type_devenir_prairie3_",
                         choices = choices_D, idEspace = "espace_prairie3_",
                         idNumericInput = "MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie3_", tagList = res)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$MOD2_nb_prairies > 0)
    
    base::lapply(1 : input$MOD2_nb_prairies, function(i){
      req(!is.null(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie3_", i)]]))
      if(input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie3_", i)]] == "" |
         input[[paste0("MOD2_type_devenir_prairie3_", i)]] == "-"){
        shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie3_", i))
        shinyjs::addCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie3_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
      }else{
        shinyjs::show(id = paste0("MOD2_rendement_devenir_prairie3_", i))
        shinyjs::removeCssClass(id = paste0("espace_prairie3_", i), class = "picker_input_prairie")
      }
    })
  })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the simple css file :

```css
.sous_titre_parametrage3{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.espace3{
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.numero_prairie{
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 94.5px;
}

.picker_input_prairie{
  padding-bottom: 74px;
}
```

My problem is that it works fine except when I reduce the value of my numericInput which allows me to create my number of different inputs...

To recreate the bug, you can enter 3 or 4 in the numericInput and then go down to 2.

Do you have any idea where my problem might be coming from?

PS: Sorry if my question isn't clear, this is the first time I've asked a question on stackoerflow.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help if you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Comment: Thanks, i going to try to give a reproducible example.

Comment: As you re-render each time you change the numeric input using the same inputIDs, you will have a problem accessing the information even if it worked.  My suggestion is to change the logic and use insertUI and removeUI to meet your needs.